# Gradle - Android - APK Split Version Error - Ambiguous method overloading for method java.lang.Integer#plus

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, apk, build.gradle

I was trying to split the apk based on architecture. It was working on another app. But not this one. This error gets happen each time trying to build the gradle.

Any ideas to solve this. I've tried some casting. but nothing happens.

Here's the full split code

```
splits {
        abi {
            enable true //enables the ABIs split mechanism
            reset() //reset the list of ABIs to be included to an empty string
            include 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
            universalApk true
        }
    }

// map for the version code
project.ext.versionCodes = ['armeabi':1, 'armeabi-v7a':2, 'arm64-v8a':3, 'mips':5, 'mips64':6, 'x86':8, 'x86_64':9]

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    // assign different version code for each output
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        output.versionCodeOverride = project.ext.versionCodes.get(output.getFilter(com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI), 0) * 1000000 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
    }
}
```

Comment: post complete error, gradle files and manifest

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh : Ok Will do

Comment: Did you solve this issue ?

Comment: @Amalp : Nope I guess. I think splitting apk is no longer needed, with the introduction of android app bundle. Don't know clearly ..